# Sentiment analysis with keras including neutral tweet

Tags: python, twitter, keras, sentiment-analysis

I'm working on a sentiment analysis project in python with keras using CNN and word2vec as an embedding method I want to detect positive, negative and neutral tweets(in my corpus I considered every negative tweets with the 0 label, positive = 1 and neutral = 2). Since I'm new in this field I have some questions,
here is a part of my code:
***Assuming that X-train and X-test contain tweets and Y-train and Y-test contain tweet's labels.

```
 if i < train_size:
     if labels[index] == 0 :
         Y_train[i, :] = [1.0, 0.0]

     elif labels[index] == 1 :
         Y_train[i, :] = [0.0, 1.0]
     else:
         Y_train[i, :] = [1.0, 1.0]

 else:

     if labels[index] == 0 :
         Y_test[i - train_size, :] = [1.0, 0.0]
     elif labels[index] == 1 :
         Y_test[i - train_size, :] = [0.0, 1.0]
     else:
         Y_test[i - train_size, :] = [1.0, 1.0]
```

in the code above you see that I considered if a related label was 0(if labels[index] == 0 :) as negative I put [1.0, 0.0] in some specific list and if the label was 1(if labels[index] == 1 :) I put [0.0, 1.0] as positive tweets and else (if labels[index] == 2 :) as neutral i put [1.0, 1.0] so just consider that the logical part af my code that i mentioned is ok.

here is my keras model:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(32, kernel_size=3, activation='elu', 
padding='same', input_shape= 
(max_tweet_length,vector_size)))
model.add(Conv1D(32, kernel_size=3, activation='elu', 
padding='same'))
model.add(Conv1D(32, kernel_size=3, activation='elu', 
padding='same'))
model.add(Conv1D(32, kernel_size=3, activation='elu', 
padding='same'))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Conv1D(32, kernel_size=2, activation='elu', 
padding='same'))
model.add(Conv1D(32, kernel_size=2, activation='elu', 
padding='same'))
model.add(Conv1D(32, kernel_size=2, activation='elu', 
padding='same'))
model.add(Conv1D(32, kernel_size=2, activation='elu', 
padding='same'))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Dense(256, activation='tanh'))
model.add(Dense(256, activation='tanh'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(2, activation='sigmoid'))
```

So in order to  predict a new input, I have this code:

```js
sentiment = model.predict(np.array(a),batch_size=1,verbose = 2)[0]
if(np.argmax(sentiment) == 0):
    print("negative")
    print('the label is')
    print(np.argmax(sentiment))
elif (np.argmax(sentiment) == 1):
    print("positive")
    print('the label is')
    print(np.argmax(sentiment))
elif (np.argmax(sentiment) ==2):
    print("neutral")
    print('the label is')
    print(np.argmax(sentiment))
```

My question contains 2 parts: 
I wanna know is it true to predict in such way? AS far as I told I considered label 2 for neutral tweets and for this reason I considered if (np.argmax(sentiment) ==2) then print neutral - Is this logical or acceptable for prediction??

I mean I considered to assign [0.1, 1.0] for neutral tweets in train and test set so If I consider 2 as neutral in prediction part, does it make any sense??

thanks a lot

---

****for regression is it true to change my train and test code in such way?
considering 0,1,2 as polarities in my corpus

```
  if i < train_size:
     if labels[index] == 0 :
         Y_train[i, :] = [1.0, 0.0]

     elif labels[index] == 1 :
         Y_train[i, :] = [0.0, 1.0]
     elif labels[index]==2
         Y_train[i, :] = [0.5, 0.5]

 else:

     if labels[index] == 0 :
         Y_test[i - train_size, :] = [1.0, 0.0]
     elif labels[index] == 1 :
         Y_test[i - train_size, :] = [0.0, 1.0]
     else:
         Y_test[i - train_size, :] = [0.5, 0.5]
```

then setting'sigmoid' for activation:

```
model.add(Dense(256, activation='tanh'))
model.add(Dense(256, activation='tanh'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(2, activation='sigmoid'))
```

and Can I predict my input tweet in the way i mentioned above??

```
 if (np.argmax(sentiment) ==2):
    print("neutral")
    print('the label is')
    print(np.argmax(sentiment))
```

*****If I used word2vec for embedding and considering 0,1,2 as polarities in my corpus Can I set labels in such way?

```
 if i < train_size:
     if labels[index] == 0 :
         Y_train[i, :] = [1.0, 0.0,0.0]

     elif labels[index] == 1 :
         Y_train[i, :] = [0.0, 1.0,0.0]
     else:
         Y_train[i, :] = [0.0, 0.0,1.0]

 else:

     if labels[index] == 0 :
         Y_test[i - train_size, :] = [1.0, 0.0,0.0]
     elif labels[index] == 1 :
         Y_test[i - train_size, :] = [0.0, 1.0,0.0]
     else:
         Y_test[i - train_size, :] = [0.0, 0.0,1.0]
```

and then for compiling:

```
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
           optimizer=Adam(lr=0.0001, decay=1e-6),
           metrics=['accuracy'])
```

thank you for your patience

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not recommend labeling your data in this way as defining your loss function to properly incentivize learning will be very difficult. The following would be more standard approaches.

**1. Classification**

label your data as it already is: simple 0,1,2. You can either label these as [`one-hot vectors`](https://www.quora.com/What-is-one-hot-encoding-and-when-is-it-used-in-data-science):

```
[1., 0., 0.]  # liberal
[0., 1., 0.]  # neutral 
[0., 0., 1.]  # conservative
```

and use the [`categorical_crossentropy`](https://keras.io/losses/#categorical_crossentropy) loss function, or simply pass in your labels as `0`, `1`, or `2` and use the [`sparse_categorical_crossentropy`](https://keras.io/losses/#sparse_categorical_crossentropy) loss function. Both should behave the same way. Either way, use 3 neurons on your output layer with `softmax` activation.

**2. Regression**

Treat labeling the sentiment as a regression task from `0` to `1` with `0` being on the left, `1` being on the right, and `0.5`. This way your model will train to predict the political ideology of the tweet on a continuous basis - which may be interesting to you. If you go this route use one output neuron with `sigmoid` activation.

---

Also, if it is of any help, I did political sentiment for a class project. I used RNNs though instead of 1D convolutions - [here](https://github.com/DylanModesitt/political-sentiment/blob/master/models/recurrent.py) is the code anyway.

Comment: thanks for your attention. As I told you I'm kinda new in this field so I have to paraphrase your suggestions in a simple way - so I should edit my basic question to check my understanding - I would appreciate if you take a loot

Comment: by the way, consider that I pass in my labels as 0,1,2 the same way as It was before. I should only use sparse_categorical_crossentropy  loss function and there isn't any problem for the rest?thank you for your patience

Comment: @ZahraBokaee you are correct for classification. For regression simply use scalars. Doing regression on your 2dim labels will most likely fail

Comment: @ZahraBokaee if you passed in labels as 0,1, or 2 and use sparse cce it will behave the same as one hot vectors with regular cce.

Comment: thanks a million - I gonna test it in my whole corpus and report the result.

Comment: @ZahraBokaee no worries. Could you accept the answer since it appears to answer your original question?